Using clipPath changes the size of the paths for an SVG
I'm encountering an issue where my SVG shrinks when I apply a clipPath to it. Despite setting the clipPathUnits to userSpaceOnUse to ensure that the clip path coordinates align with the SVG’s viewBox, the size of the SVG appears to reduce significantly. Here’s the code I'm working with:


<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            svg {
                background: linear-gradient(-45deg,#279a94,#a79353,#ff8e26,#db5157,#0077f2);
                clip-path: url(#myClip);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        <path d="M 164.305 329.606 L 164.305 350.016 C 164.305 368.136 181.085 374.836 199.205 374.836 L 221.265 374.836 C 224.165 401.206 228.255 398.846 228.255 410.216 C 228.255 410.216 228.255 415.586 232.135 415.586 L 233.475 415.586 C 237.355 415.586 237.355 410.216 237.355 410.216 C 237.355 398.786 241.485 401.206 244.385 374.836 L 265.105 374.836 C 283.225 374.836 303.365 368.136 303.365 350.016 L 303.365 330.126 C 260.215 334.896 205.075 334.716 164.315 329.606 L 164.305 329.606 Z" />
        <path d="M 164.305 265.316 L 164.305 294.856 C 205.065 300.076 260.205 300.256 303.355 295.376 L 303.355 265.456 C 279.385 266.756 258.085 267.446 234.955 267.446 C 211.825 267.446 185.885 266.706 164.305 265.316 Z" />
        <path d="M 303.355 230.126 L 303.355 196.256 C 303.355 184.256 293.355 173.736 283.695 167.966 L 298.065 141.276 C 302.585 133.786 299.285 123.956 291.795 119.436 C 284.305 114.916 274.045 111.626 269.525 119.116 L 245.875 151.866 L 217.465 151.866 L 194.245 119.116 C 189.725 111.626 179.895 112.056 172.405 116.576 C 164.915 121.096 162.485 132.356 167.005 139.846 L 182.375 166.266 C 171.755 171.756 164.295 183.536 164.295 196.256 L 164.295 229.606 C 205.055 234.826 260.195 235.006 303.345 230.126 L 303.355 230.126 Z" />
        <path d="M 149.915 347.076 L 143.555 353.486 L 141.985 355.376 C 134.375 363.726 123.485 368.506 112.085 368.506 C 101.975 368.506 92.325 364.786 84.905 358.026 C 76.965 350.796 72.325 340.846 71.815 330.026 C 71.315 319.196 75.015 308.866 82.255 300.926 L 115.085 261.416 L 149.925 219.496 L 149.925 196.246 C 149.925 186.916 153.115 177.656 158.505 169.886 L 83.895 257.766 L 60.705 285.076 C 49.235 297.656 45.445 314.006 46.235 331.116 C 47.035 348.226 55.445 363.956 68.025 375.426 C 79.785 386.146 95.595 392.046 111.585 392.046 C 126.605 392.046 141.345 386.756 152.735 377.326 L 157.675 372.336 C 152.725 366.216 149.925 358.646 149.925 350.006 L 149.925 347.076 L 149.915 347.076 Z" />
        <path d="M 404.755 285.086 L 381.785 258.036 L 306.865 169.896 C 312.255 177.666 315.335 186.936 315.335 196.256 L 315.335 219.506 L 350.435 261.626 L 383.175 300.936 C 390.405 308.876 394.125 319.206 393.625 330.036 C 393.125 340.856 388.475 350.806 380.545 358.036 C 373.125 364.796 363.475 368.516 353.365 368.516 C 341.965 368.516 331.055 363.726 323.455 355.386 L 321.805 353.496 L 315.335 347.086 L 315.335 350.016 C 315.335 358.656 312.645 366.226 307.695 372.346 L 312.715 377.336 C 324.105 386.766 338.855 392.056 353.875 392.056 C 369.865 392.056 385.675 386.156 397.435 375.436 C 410.015 363.966 418.425 348.236 419.225 331.126 C 420.025 314.016 416.215 297.666 404.755 285.086 Z" />
        <path d="M 370.909 171.859 C 368.735 171.87 366.782 170.532 366.008 168.5 L 357.643 146.746 C 357.3 145.86 356.6 145.159 355.713 144.817 L 333.953 136.445 C 330.181 134.997 329.391 130.008 332.531 127.465 C 332.959 127.118 333.439 126.841 333.953 126.643 L 355.707 118.278 C 356.593 117.935 357.294 117.235 357.636 116.348 L 366.008 94.589 C 367.456 90.816 372.445 90.026 374.988 93.166 C 375.335 93.594 375.612 94.074 375.809 94.589 L 384.175 116.342 C 384.517 117.229 385.219 117.929 386.105 118.272 L 407.732 126.593 C 409.845 127.376 411.241 129.4 411.224 131.653 C 411.191 133.788 409.86 135.687 407.864 136.445 L 386.111 144.811 C 385.225 145.153 384.524 145.854 384.181 146.74 L 375.809 168.5 C 375.036 170.532 373.083 171.87 370.909 171.859 Z M 384.946 118.349 Z" />
        <path d="M 422.669 228.25 C 421.111 228.258 419.712 227.299 419.157 225.843 L 413.162 210.252 C 412.916 209.617 412.415 209.115 411.779 208.87 L 396.184 202.87 C 393.481 201.832 392.915 198.257 395.165 196.434 C 395.472 196.186 395.816 195.987 396.184 195.845 L 411.775 189.85 C 412.41 189.604 412.912 189.103 413.157 188.467 L 419.157 172.873 C 420.195 170.169 423.77 169.603 425.593 171.853 C 425.841 172.16 426.04 172.504 426.181 172.873 L 432.177 188.463 C 432.422 189.098 432.925 189.6 433.56 189.846 L 449.059 195.809 C 450.574 196.37 451.574 197.821 451.562 199.436 C 451.538 200.966 450.584 202.327 449.154 202.87 L 433.564 208.866 C 432.929 209.111 432.427 209.613 432.181 210.248 L 426.181 225.843 C 425.627 227.299 424.228 228.258 422.669 228.25 Z M 432.729 189.901 Z" />
    </clipPath>
</svg>

</body>

</html>



Note that if I remove the clipPath node, it displays a different size.


<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M 164.305 329.606 L 164.305 350.016 C 164.305 368.136 181.085 374.836 199.205 374.836 L 221.265 374.836 C 224.165 401.206 228.255 398.846 228.255 410.216 C 228.255 410.216 228.255 415.586 232.135 415.586 L 233.475 415.586 C 237.355 415.586 237.355 410.216 237.355 410.216 C 237.355 398.786 241.485 401.206 244.385 374.836 L 265.105 374.836 C 283.225 374.836 303.365 368.136 303.365 350.016 L 303.365 330.126 C 260.215 334.896 205.075 334.716 164.315 329.606 L 164.305 329.606 Z" />
    <path d="M 164.305 265.316 L 164.305 294.856 C 205.065 300.076 260.205 300.256 303.355 295.376 L 303.355 265.456 C 279.385 266.756 258.085 267.446 234.955 267.446 C 211.825 267.446 185.885 266.706 164.305 265.316 Z" />
    <path d="M 303.355 230.126 L 303.355 196.256 C 303.355 184.256 293.355 173.736 283.695 167.966 L 298.065 141.276 C 302.585 133.786 299.285 123.956 291.795 119.436 C 284.305 114.916 274.045 111.626 269.525 119.116 L 245.875 151.866 L 217.465 151.866 L 194.245 119.116 C 189.725 111.626 179.895 112.056 172.405 116.576 C 164.915 121.096 162.485 132.356 167.005 139.846 L 182.375 166.266 C 171.755 171.756 164.295 183.536 164.295 196.256 L 164.295 229.606 C 205.055 234.826 260.195 235.006 303.345 230.126 L 303.355 230.126 Z" />
    <path d="M 149.915 347.076 L 143.555 353.486 L 141.985 355.376 C 134.375 363.726 123.485 368.506 112.085 368.506 C 101.975 368.506 92.325 364.786 84.905 358.026 C 76.965 350.796 72.325 340.846 71.815 330.026 C 71.315 319.196 75.015 308.866 82.255 300.926 L 115.085 261.416 L 149.925 219.496 L 149.925 196.246 C 149.925 186.916 153.115 177.656 158.505 169.886 L 83.895 257.766 L 60.705 285.076 C 49.235 297.656 45.445 314.006 46.235 331.116 C 47.035 348.226 55.445 363.956 68.025 375.426 C 79.785 386.146 95.595 392.046 111.585 392.046 C 126.605 392.046 141.345 386.756 152.735 377.326 L 157.675 372.336 C 152.725 366.216 149.925 358.646 149.925 350.006 L 149.925 347.076 L 149.915 347.076 Z" />
    <path d="M 404.755 285.086 L 381.785 258.036 L 306.865 169.896 C 312.255 177.666 315.335 186.936 315.335 196.256 L 315.335 219.506 L 350.435 261.626 L 383.175 300.936 C 390.405 308.876 394.125 319.206 393.625 330.036 C 393.125 340.856 388.475 350.806 380.545 358.036 C 373.125 364.796 363.475 368.516 353.365 368.516 C 341.965 368.516 331.055 363.726 323.455 355.386 L 321.805 353.496 L 315.335 347.086 L 315.335 350.016 C 315.335 358.656 312.645 366.226 307.695 372.346 L 312.715 377.336 C 324.105 386.766 338.855 392.056 353.875 392.056 C 369.865 392.056 385.675 386.156 397.435 375.436 C 410.015 363.966 418.425 348.236 419.225 331.126 C 420.025 314.016 416.215 297.666 404.755 285.086 Z" />
    <path d="M 370.909 171.859 C 368.735 171.87 366.782 170.532 366.008 168.5 L 357.643 146.746 C 357.3 145.86 356.6 145.159 355.713 144.817 L 333.953 136.445 C 330.181 134.997 329.391 130.008 332.531 127.465 C 332.959 127.118 333.439 126.841 333.953 126.643 L 355.707 118.278 C 356.593 117.935 357.294 117.235 357.636 116.348 L 366.008 94.589 C 367.456 90.816 372.445 90.026 374.988 93.166 C 375.335 93.594 375.612 94.074 375.809 94.589 L 384.175 116.342 C 384.517 117.229 385.219 117.929 386.105 118.272 L 407.732 126.593 C 409.845 127.376 411.241 129.4 411.224 131.653 C 411.191 133.788 409.86 135.687 407.864 136.445 L 386.111 144.811 C 385.225 145.153 384.524 145.854 384.181 146.74 L 375.809 168.5 C 375.036 170.532 373.083 171.87 370.909 171.859 Z M 384.946 118.349 Z" />
    <path d="M 422.669 228.25 C 421.111 228.258 419.712 227.299 419.157 225.843 L 413.162 210.252 C 412.916 209.617 412.415 209.115 411.779 208.87 L 396.184 202.87 C 393.481 201.832 392.915 198.257 395.165 196.434 C 395.472 196.186 395.816 195.987 396.184 195.845 L 411.775 189.85 C 412.41 189.604 412.912 189.103 413.157 188.467 L 419.157 172.873 C 420.195 170.169 423.77 169.603 425.593 171.853 C 425.841 172.16 426.04 172.504 426.181 172.873 L 432.177 188.463 C 432.422 189.098 432.925 189.6 433.56 189.846 L 449.059 195.809 C 450.574 196.37 451.574 197.821 451.562 199.436 C 451.538 200.966 450.584 202.327 449.154 202.87 L 433.564 208.866 C 432.929 209.111 432.427 209.613 432.181 210.248 L 426.181 225.843 C 425.627 227.299 424.228 228.258 422.669 228.25 Z M 432.729 189.901 Z" />
</svg>

</body>

</html>



I've tried altering CSS and other attributes to make it so that the clipPath honors the viewBox, but I haven't figured it out.

Do you absolutely need to set the color through the CSS background property on the container SVG element? Otherwise, and if your gradient always have 5 stops, then you could achieve the expected result by clipping a <rect> that's inside the SVG container (and thus on which the viewBox would apply) and set its fill to a <linearGradient>: https://jsfiddle.net/mnzuxeov/

Have a look at PaulLebeau's answer: "Complex SVG clip-path responsive". In short: add clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" and  transform="scale(0.002)" to get a responsive clip-path. Currently your clip-path will keep it's size (500x500 units)

Clip-paths are annoying. They are not that flexible when defined in CSS. They will not scale and therefore needs to be the exact size.
I have two suggestions. Either use the SVG image (the entire image, not a mask or clip-path) as a CSS mask-image (can be a data URI like here or a reference to a SVG file). A CSS mask has different CSS properties like mask-size, mask-position, mask-repeat etc. that can be used for setting up the right mask of the HTML element.
The other suggestion is to use a clip-path of the icon in the SVG and then use it to clip a rectangle in the SVG. ANd then define the linear gradient in the SVG as well.


body {
  display: flex;
}

svg, div {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.clipped {
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #279a94, #a79353, #ff8e26, #db5157, #0077f2);
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  mask-size: 100%;
  mask-position: center;
 }
<div class="clipped" style="width: 300px; height: 300px"></div>

<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="myClip" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <path d="M 164.305 329.606 L 164.305 350.016 C 164.305 368.136 181.085 374.836 199.205 374.836 L 221.265 374.836 C 224.165 401.206 228.255 398.846 228.255 410.216 C 228.255 410.216 228.255 415.586 232.135 415.586 L 233.475 415.586 C 237.355 415.586 237.355 410.216 237.355 410.216 C 237.355 398.786 241.485 401.206 244.385 374.836 L 265.105 374.836 C 283.225 374.836 303.365 368.136 303.365 350.016 L 303.365 330.126 C 260.215 334.896 205.075 334.716 164.315 329.606 L 164.305 329.606 Z" />
      <path d="M 164.305 265.316 L 164.305 294.856 C 205.065 300.076 260.205 300.256 303.355 295.376 L 303.355 265.456 C 279.385 266.756 258.085 267.446 234.955 267.446 C 211.825 267.446 185.885 266.706 164.305 265.316 Z" />
      <path d="M 303.355 230.126 L 303.355 196.256 C 303.355 184.256 293.355 173.736 283.695 167.966 L 298.065 141.276 C 302.585 133.786 299.285 123.956 291.795 119.436 C 284.305 114.916 274.045 111.626 269.525 119.116 L 245.875 151.866 L 217.465 151.866 L 194.245 119.116 C 189.725 111.626 179.895 112.056 172.405 116.576 C 164.915 121.096 162.485 132.356 167.005 139.846 L 182.375 166.266 C 171.755 171.756 164.295 183.536 164.295 196.256 L 164.295 229.606 C 205.055 234.826 260.195 235.006 303.345 230.126 L 303.355 230.126 Z" />
      <path d="M 149.915 347.076 L 143.555 353.486 L 141.985 355.376 C 134.375 363.726 123.485 368.506 112.085 368.506 C 101.975 368.506 92.325 364.786 84.905 358.026 C 76.965 350.796 72.325 340.846 71.815 330.026 C 71.315 319.196 75.015 308.866 82.255 300.926 L 115.085 261.416 L 149.925 219.496 L 149.925 196.246 C 149.925 186.916 153.115 177.656 158.505 169.886 L 83.895 257.766 L 60.705 285.076 C 49.235 297.656 45.445 314.006 46.235 331.116 C 47.035 348.226 55.445 363.956 68.025 375.426 C 79.785 386.146 95.595 392.046 111.585 392.046 C 126.605 392.046 141.345 386.756 152.735 377.326 L 157.675 372.336 C 152.725 366.216 149.925 358.646 149.925 350.006 L 149.925 347.076 L 149.915 347.076 Z" />
      <path d="M 404.755 285.086 L 381.785 258.036 L 306.865 169.896 C 312.255 177.666 315.335 186.936 315.335 196.256 L 315.335 219.506 L 350.435 261.626 L 383.175 300.936 C 390.405 308.876 394.125 319.206 393.625 330.036 C 393.125 340.856 388.475 350.806 380.545 358.036 C 373.125 364.796 363.475 368.516 353.365 368.516 C 341.965 368.516 331.055 363.726 323.455 355.386 L 321.805 353.496 L 315.335 347.086 L 315.335 350.016 C 315.335 358.656 312.645 366.226 307.695 372.346 L 312.715 377.336 C 324.105 386.766 338.855 392.056 353.875 392.056 C 369.865 392.056 385.675 386.156 397.435 375.436 C 410.015 363.966 418.425 348.236 419.225 331.126 C 420.025 314.016 416.215 297.666 404.755 285.086 Z" />
      <path d="M 370.909 171.859 C 368.735 171.87 366.782 170.532 366.008 168.5 L 357.643 146.746 C 357.3 145.86 356.6 145.159 355.713 144.817 L 333.953 136.445 C 330.181 134.997 329.391 130.008 332.531 127.465 C 332.959 127.118 333.439 126.841 333.953 126.643 L 355.707 118.278 C 356.593 117.935 357.294 117.235 357.636 116.348 L 366.008 94.589 C 367.456 90.816 372.445 90.026 374.988 93.166 C 375.335 93.594 375.612 94.074 375.809 94.589 L 384.175 116.342 C 384.517 117.229 385.219 117.929 386.105 118.272 L 407.732 126.593 C 409.845 127.376 411.241 129.4 411.224 131.653 C 411.191 133.788 409.86 135.687 407.864 136.445 L 386.111 144.811 C 385.225 145.153 384.524 145.854 384.181 146.74 L 375.809 168.5 C 375.036 170.532 373.083 171.87 370.909 171.859 Z M 384.946 118.349 Z" />
      <path d="M 422.669 228.25 C 421.111 228.258 419.712 227.299 419.157 225.843 L 413.162 210.252 C 412.916 209.617 412.415 209.115 411.779 208.87 L 396.184 202.87 C 393.481 201.832 392.915 198.257 395.165 196.434 C 395.472 196.186 395.816 195.987 396.184 195.845 L 411.775 189.85 C 412.41 189.604 412.912 189.103 413.157 188.467 L 419.157 172.873 C 420.195 170.169 423.77 169.603 425.593 171.853 C 425.841 172.16 426.04 172.504 426.181 172.873 L 432.177 188.463 C 432.422 189.098 432.925 189.6 433.56 189.846 L 449.059 195.809 C 450.574 196.37 451.574 197.821 451.562 199.436 C 451.538 200.966 450.584 202.327 449.154 202.87 L 433.564 208.866 C 432.929 209.111 432.427 209.613 432.181 210.248 L 426.181 225.843 C 425.627 227.299 424.228 228.258 422.669 228.25 Z M 432.729 189.901 Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="g1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="1" y2="1">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#0077f2" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#db5157" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ff8e26" />
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#a79353" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#279a94" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect width="500" height="500" fill="url(#g1)" clip-path="url(#myClip)" />
</svg>




Thank you! Totally spaced on using a mask-image.
